# 'Effect > Stylize > Rounded corners' not available in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, windows

Well the question pretty much sums it up. I'm running Illustrator CS6 on Windows and after selecting a shape and wanting to round the corners by going to `Effect > Stylize` I'm looking for the option `rounded corners`...

All I'm seeing is "Glowing edges", and, well, that's not very helpful is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two sections in this drop down menu. You are looking at the bottom one (labeled Photoshop). The top one (labeled Illustrator) has the same stylize group, but with the effects you seek.

Comment: I.. I.. I can't believe I did that stupid mistake! Thanks for pointing that out, I feel like an idiot now. :-/

Comment: No worries @Relborg I got a kick out of it.

Comment: We were all new once. At least you asked for help instead of giving up. :)

Comment: I done the exact same thing!